# Hosted inferno will not run wm

Tags: x11

I was able to compile inferno on my raspberry pi. While emu and the console work absolutely fine, I tried to start wm. Instead of wm loading toolbar, I get a black screen, then back to the terminal, then this:

```
; wm/wm
emu: bad display depth 16 chan r5g6b5 xscreendepth 16
```

Why is this happening? Did I compile wm wrong, or something? I appreciate any help you guys can give me; I realize not everyone deals with inferno on a daily basis.